# Magento Update to 1.7.0.1 causes pricing to display as 0.0

Tags: magento

I updated my website, and as you can see in the link below...
http://dokha.co/index.php/dokha-medwakh-tobacco/sample-bag-of-dokha.html

No matter what option you pick, the price displays as 0.00

I cant figure this out. Any ideas?

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reindexing?

You probably should reindex the catalog product prices index, but after an upgrade it may be a good idea to reindex everything you can.

Comment: I am almost certain it is an index. The price is $4 when you add it to cart.

Comment: I have reindexed everything And the prices still remain the same for me.

Comment: Do you have anything extensions installed that modify the way pricing works on the site? Did you modify the code that displays the price on your product page? Something is off somewhere if reindexing did not solve the problem.

Comment: Hello Josh, sorry for the delay, I have been in the hospital over the past few days. I have a module installed to manage quantities on custom products. I will disable it and see if this causes a fix. Then i will hunt for an update and the like, thank you for your help sir.